# Replace column entry with sum of other column entries

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

Let's say I have a file that contains these lines:

```
02.03.14    14.50   14.50   0.00    Desc
02.03.14    17.00   0.00    17.00   Desc
01.03.14    2.82    1.68    calc    Desc
02.03.14    1.04    0.00    1.04    Desc
06.03.14    6.00    0.00    6.00    Desc
08.03.14    11.76   2.98    calc    Desc
10.03.14    3.27    0.00    3.27    Desc
```

I want to replace all column entries containing `calc` (only appearing in the `4th` column) to contain the difference between the `3nd` and `2nd` column, so `4th=3rd-2nd`.

How can I do so?

Comment: @1_CR Now it's possible to use any tool you know :)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sed can't do arithmetic¹. Use awk instead.

```
awk '
    $4 == "calc" {sub(/calc(  |\t)/, sprintf("%-6.2f", $3 - $2))}
    1'
```

The `1` at the end means to print everything (after any preceding transformation). Instead of the text substitution with `sub`, you could assign to `$4`, but doing so replaces inter-column space (which can be any sequence of spaces and tabs) by a single space character. If your columns are tab-separated, you can use

```
awk '
    BEGIN {ORS = "\t"}
    $4 == "calc" {$4 = sprintf("%.2f", $3 - $2))}
    1'
```

¹  <sub>Yes, yes, technically it can since it's Turing-complete. But not in any sane way.</sub>

Comment: Thanks @Gilles. I made some changes, though, because I have tabs instead of whitespaces as delimiters for each row, so I added a tab after calc and after the sprintf.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F "\t" '$4 == "calc" {$4 = $3-$2}1' OFS='\t' file
```